# How to show users "My Open Tasks" with due date in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, tasks, cswp

Microsoft decided to remove task aggregation known from SharePoint 2013 when releasing SharePoint 2016. In SharePoint Online this pretty good feature is missing as well. **Can anyone tell us what Microsoft thinks about how to get an overview on all open tasks assigned to you as user?**

I know - there is a Content Search Web Part (CSWP). OOTB it looks pretty unprofessional (no picture with tasks) and has problems showing due dates in tasks (shows due date if task has only due date but not start date).

What I did: CSWP with this query "ContentTypeId:0x0108* AssignedTo:{User.Name} StatusOWSCHCS<>Completed". Template "Picture on the left, 3 lines on right". Properties: Title, SiteTitle, RefinableDate00 (which the due date crawled property is mapped in our tenant).

**Any better solution known? How do other customers keep track on tasks in SharePoint Online?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: "what Microsoft thinks" I don't think anyone here can answer that! As to why the User Tasks web part no longer works: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82503/user-tasks-webpart-does-not-display-any-tasks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the additional features of the new Task List (such as the Timeline), then you can create the older style task lists, which still work with the User Tasks rollup web part.

```
https://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_layouts/15/slnew.aspx?ListTemplate=107
```

For a list of the template IDs see: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/02/sharepoint-2013-list-and-library.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This seems to be a solution if you do not have any existing task lists in your farm/tenant. As I got lots of sites using the recent task list for tasks I cannot use this solution. Next problem is that I would not know how long MS would support this old style task list. I wonder how other customers keep track of the tasks in SharePoint Online?

Comment: The search web parts are probably the first choice to list the tasks in a page. But, these are only up to date as the last search crawl. Otherwise, users can use the "Tasks" option in the waffle button to see their own tasks. This opens in Outlook. These tasks are also pulled from search crawls.

Comment: If it is ok that most resently added (not in the Search index yet) Tasks is not listed then it is posible to show the current values by adding a js funktion that will pull the values from the actual objects. However this script will require a developer